# delete hidden value field when delete the jQuery autocomplete value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I do have a jQuery ui autocomplete that shows the name of a company and on a hidden textbox I got the CompanyNumber(an special id that the company where I work uses to identify each company) and everything works fine it retrieves and shows the company name and gets the due CompanyNumber in the hidden field...but

Problem: when the user deletes the name of the company the companyNumber value in the hidden field remains and I want it to dissapears too, how can achieve that? any help please?

this is my jQuery code and the two fields

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#SearchString").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action(actionName: "autocompletar", controllerName: "Borrar")',
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: { prefix: request.term },
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                return { value: item.np, label: item.empresa };
                            }))
                        }
                    })
                },
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    if (ui.item) {
                        $("#numeroPatronal").val(ui.item.value);
                        $("#SearchString").val(ui.item.label);
                        event.preventDefault();
                        return false;
                    }
                },
                focus: function (event, ui) {
                    $("#numeroPatronal").val(ui.item.value);
                    // $("#txtmasterserach").val(ui.item.label);
                    event.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                },
                messages: {
                    noResults: "", results: ""
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert("Error" + res.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>



 <div class="container col-md-10 col-md-offset-3">
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
       <p> Empresa: @Html.TextBox("SearchString") </p>
       <p> Número Patronal: @Html.TextBox("numeroPatronal") </p>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        }
    </div>
```

first I select from the autocomplete field the desired company[image]

once the company name is selected and fills the companyNumber field with the due information (the two fields have info but I just erased because it is non public)
[image]

but if I erase the company Name from the autocomplete textbox the CompanyNumber of the company just erased reamins and I want it to dissapears too
[image]

the jQuery function

```
 $('#SearchString').on('input', function () {
                if (!$('#SearchString').val()) {
                    $('#numeroPatronal').val('');
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

This example should help you, since I can't see your HTML code, just put different id into your input, then add an `input` event to 1st input, when 1st input is empty, also empty the 2nd input.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#input1').on('input', function() {
    if (!$('#input1').val()) {
      $('#input2').val('');
    }
  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Input 1: <input id="input1" value="11111"></div>
<div>Input 2: <input id="input2" value="22222"></div>
```

Comment: thanks, I´m sure I did not explain well, what I want is that when the user erases/select and delete/supr the value selected from the autocomplete dropdown the due CompanyNumber also dissapears, I just edited my question with an image of no value in companyName(because I erased) and still has the value in CompanyNumber...thanks for any help

Comment: @PabloTobar could you show the rendered HTML? like inspect those input in the browser

Comment: @PabloTobar ok try the updated code, I don't have your HTML code but this should help you write your own

Comment: @PabloTobar just put this function inside your document ready, and add id to each of your input

Comment: thanks, but If a select a companyName and just tab the companyNumber got erased, I just edited my question with the code you posted.